# F# Fake error Build

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code

I'm new to F# with VSCode.

I've installed FAKE and when I want to build my first program I have this build failer message :

```
Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) dans D:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:ligne 626
```

I have no directory **D:\code**

What did I miss ?

Thank you

**Problem solved** : I change in the name of my working directory "F#" to "FSharp" and now it works.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: for simple stuff you don't need to use Fake, you can just use MsBuild in VsCode. Try Ctrl-P build current project.

Comment: @ s952163 OK Thank you.

Comment: For completeness: The `D:\code\fake` directory is the one *from* which the code that's throwing the error was compiled on the machine that built the package. That's a normal .NET behavior and can be confusing if you don't know what it's trying tell you, because you often end up seeing people's OS usernames etc. in those error messages.

Comment: Usefull tip ! It's exactly what happens ! I didn't search anymore. I saw yesterday that it was knowned that characters like # could give errors with VS Code